# Route 53 stop working "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, certbot

I have an EC2 instance. A year ago I linked it to a domain. I used Route 53 and I remember that I used at some point Certbot for encryption and I used namespaces that I copied from the AWS console and pasted into the domain manager. I barely remember what I did but it works.

Until now.

When I open the domain name I get a "This site can’t be reached" message.

I tried to check in a [dns checker](https://dnschecker.org/) and it couldn't identify my domain (lifnim . ga feel free to try it yourself). I restart the server and restart Certbot.

Maybe a good starting point will be to check why the IP from the elastic IP from the AWS console produces 404 error.

I wish that I could explain better what I did but I don't think that I ever understood what I have done in first place.
It's so frustrating since a week ago everything works properly. Are there any services that expired after a year? I install my server about a year ago..

Thanks!

P.S. Maybe I also used reverse proxy through [this](https://github.com/rekby/lets-proxy2) repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Freenom very recently lost control of the .ga ccTLD due to mismanagement.
>
> All .ga domains were deleted, including yours.
>
> Your certificates is only valid for your former lifnim.ga domain. Accessing  your webserver using the IP address is not valid, because your certificate is not intended for that purpose.

Someone answer me here:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/if-https-ip-gives-not-secure-will-https-domain-com-works/199717/2